# In a module, how can I include submodules for environments where they may not be installed, without modifying sys.path?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am writing a Python module, call it module A. Module A depends on module B which depends on modules C and D, none of which are standard libraries, and none of which are my own. Module A is for use in Python environments where it is either known for certain, or else highly unlikely, that modules B, C and D are installed out of the box, such as Sublime Text, Pythonista, or some other tool that has its own Python environment.

Now what if I wanted to incorporate module A along with modules B - D, into a package for a (non-developer) end user, let's call it Package 1, for use in one environment (say Sublime Text), and also another, Package 2, for another environment (say for Pythonista). I want to bundle Module A, along with its dependencies, Modules B, C and D, into both packages, **such that the import paths in all four modules can remain the same in both, while preserving any relative imports that may exist inside of Modules B, C and D?**

This all might be for many reasons, but mine are:

- I want to be able to maintain Module A as an independent submodule.
- I want to be able to pull changes in Modules B - D into Module A, and by extension, into Packages 1 and 2, without modifying the import paths in all of them.
- I want the end user to at least have the option not to manually install Modules B - D in order to use Packages 1 and 2.

Now suppose, in addition, that the developer of one such intended environment (Sublime Text) asks that this be done without modifying `sys.path`...

For instance, I have the following folder structure:

```
+ Package 1
  + __init__.py
  + (etc.)
  |
  +-- module_a
  |   + __init__.py
  |   + code.py
  |
  +-- module_b
  |   + __init__.py
  |   + ...
  +-- module_c
  |   + __init__.py
  |   + ...
  +-- module_d
      ...
```

Then in Module A, I can write:

```
from ..module_b import something
```

But since Module B's own path is not in the import path, if Module B needs a relative import from its own folder, it cannot find it unless I go into `module_b` and change:

```
from module_b.something_else import SomethingElse
```

to:

```
from .something_else import SomethingElse
```

... and so on. This seems like a mess, and seems to be the case no matter how I build the Package folder. I would like to know if there is a way to do this while adhering to the request not to modify `sys.path`.

Comment: do you want to avoid changing PYTHONPATH as well?

Comment: This is madness—a package can and should be expected to depend on its qualified name.  For example, there’s no relative syntax for `a/b.py` to import `a` itself.  You can package Python packages, of course, but as (say) a *Debian* package, not another *Python* package.

Comment: @SteveJ I’m assuming that would yield the same objection from the ST developer. The developer requests using relative imports instead.